# Pdflatex for windows

Tags: windows, latex, cygwin, pdflatex

Does anyone know how to convert .tex files to .pdf in windows? I tried cygwin but it said the command "pdflatex" was not recognised

Thanks
Philip

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There's no reason to complicate things with Cygwin. Go download and install a TeX distribution for Windows - I personally use [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive), but various other distributions are available, such as [MikTeX](http://www.miktex.org/) or [W32TeX](http://w32tex.org/).

If you want to use UTF-8 for your bibliography, and you're using BibTeX, I recommend using bibtexu instead of the regular bibtex (since bibtex doesn't actually support UTF-8). There's a download on the [W32TeX site](http://w32tex.org/).

Comment: I've used MikTeX and it works great.  However I've tried to install it three times over the years and only once did it actually work.  I was not smart enough (or motivated enough) to figure out why the not-working installs did not work.

Comment: Yes, installing used to be kind of difficult. Thankfully, Portable MikTeX now exists (http://miktex.org/portable/about). It's intended to be run from a USB stick that you carry around with you, but as a side effect it is also utterly trivial to install and works just as well as the older method.

Comment: I tried a couple of hours installing TeX Live in Windows 7, but got all kinds of errors, gave up, and installed MikTeX (the regular 64-bit version) easily.

Comment: I disagree that installing software using Cygwin's package manager is complicating things. It actually makes the whole system more reproductible, like good distros do. I always highly recommend using Cygwin over messy native windows ports, for a better overall UNIX workflow.

Comment: FYI: TeX Live worked fine at the 1st try for Winwdows 10.

Answer (score 9):

If you need to stick with cygwin, install *texlive* and *texlive-collection-latex*

Comment: I have those packages installed, yet I have the same problem.

Comment: After installing `texlive-collection-latex`, it makes `pdflatex` available in the command line, but pandoc still complains about `pdflatex` not existing.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai [This](http://superuser.com/a/1053281/) answer on superuser should probably solve that problem

Answer (score 5):

The following command worked for me, under cygwin. I installed pandoc 1.13.2 and MiKTeX 2.9.5105 64-bit. Then I ran:

```
pandoc -s \
--latex-engine='C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe'  \
-f markdown_github -t latex \
"my-file.md" -o "my-file.pdf"
```

The key here is that I gave the full path for MiKText's pdflatex.exe in the --latex-engine key, in quotes, using the windows path (as the pandoc I installed is the windows pandoc, it requires windows-style paths to find resources).

I used -f markdown_github because of the file format of my-file.md

I used -t latext but that's optional AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `tetex`(and optionally `tetex-extra`) package in Cygwin worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

MikTex and [texify](https://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/texify.html) work for me under plain Windows.